# FragmentManager know when a fragment resumed

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I have a `FragmentManager` that I am using to add `Fragments` onto the `backStack`.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
PUCCoursesSubjectList detail = new PUCCoursesSubjectList();
detail.item = item;

ft.add(R.id.container_frame, detail, "courses_detail");
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Once I have a few `Fragments` on the stack, I pop one off, but I need to know when the previous fragment is shown again.

**It seems that `onResume` doesn't apply here. Is there another method that I should be using to know when a `Fragment`, that is already in the `FragmentManger`, appears?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pop your fragment, you could get your other fragment from the fragment manager by the tag you provided and call a public method in your fragment.

```
YourFragment fragment = (YourFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FRAGMENT_TAG");

if (fragment != null) {
   fragment.callMethod();
}
```

Comment: Where would I call this from? From a method in the Fragment that I am popping? From `onDestroy()`?

Comment: Depends where you need it. You can call it anywhere you have access to the context (Activity hosting your Fragments). In your case you mentioned that you pop one fragment off, you can call it there?

Comment: Yeah, just tested it in the `onDestroy()` method of the popped Fragment and it works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer could not work: getFragmentManager may return null in some case (i.e. Activity has been destroyed)

Now it's better to use Lifecycle, like in the next example:

```
  if( getLifecycle().getCurrentState().isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) )
  {
      // Do whatever you need
  }
```

Comment: May I know from where I have to use this code? I mean fragment or activity?

Comment: In both, just use androidx versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can check by the tag if it is visible and not null by suing the tag

```
MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MY_FRAGMENT");
if (myFragment != null && myFragment.isVisible()) {
   // add your code here
}
```